# Can I stop Visual Studio compilation when it already started?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Sometime I mistakenly press build (or Debug/F5) in Visual Studio, which result in a build process. I don't know how to stop this, stop debugging button is disabled, and normally I have to wait until the compilation is finished before I can code again (this might take a while if my solution has quite a number of csproj).

Any idea how to stop the compilation process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press the key combination <kbd>Ctrl + Break</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause|Break</kbd> to abort the build.

Comment: Would have been first if it hadn't been for a couple of impossible Captchas.

Comment: Don't be so sure, Captchas were in my way too ;-))

Answer (score 2):

That's easy - Press Ctrl+Break (Works only from VS2005 upto 2010)
I suggest to download for your reference this document
[Visual Studio 2010 Default Key Bindings](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13189)

Answer (score 0):

Press the Control Button and then Break (pause break)